# Boundedness of a subset of sequence space.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Is $P=\{x\in \ell^1:||x||_{\ell^1}\leq 1\}$ is a bounded set in Banach Space $(\ell^2,||.||_{\ell^2})$

I think NO, because $x_n=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots \frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1}\dots )$ is in the set $P$ but since $ 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\dots \frac{1}{n}$ diverges it doesn't belong to any ball in $(l^1,||.||_1)$.

Wait, I think I am wrong as $x_n=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots \frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1}\dots )$ doesn't belong to $l^1$

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Suggestion: write down the definition of a bounded set, and verify to yourself that $P$ is nothing but the unit ball of $\ell^1$.

Comment: @uniquesolution I tried, but couldn't get anywhere. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's important to precise that $\ell^1(\mathbb R)\subset \ell^2(\mathbb R)$ (otherwise, the question has no sense). A counter example is $$y_n=\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_{\ell^1}},$$
where $x_n=(\underbrace{n,...,n}_{n\text{ times}},0,...,0,...)$.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I had missed _2 in $||x||_2$ in the definition of $P$, otherwise It was way too trivial

Comment: @SunShine: Be precise in your question, what you said doesn't make sense. What is $\|x\|_2$ in this context ?

Comment: It has to be $(\sum_{i}|x_i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3 \dots)$ Please note that the summation varies from $i=1$ to $\infty$

Comment: So you want to show that $P$ is not a bounded subset of $\ell^2$ ? First it's important to precise that $\ell^1\subset \ell^2$ (otherwise the question makes no sense). Set $x_n=(\underbrace{n,...,n}_{n\ times},0,...,)$, then $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_{\ell^1}}$ will do the job. @SunShine

Comment: Thanks, got your point. You might want to edit the answer, so I will accept the answer

Comment: @SunShine: Done. I also edited your question ;-)

Comment: Well, proving $\ell^1(\mathbb R)\subset \ell^2(\mathbb R)$ is easily done using comparisons of terms.

Comment: @SunShine: Yes sure, but if you don't mention it, the question has anyway no sense... The fact that it's "easy" to prove doesn't implies that it's elementary ;-)